# How to cronjob task schedule every 40minutes?

Tags: laravel, cron

How to run 1 job every 40 minutes or 45 minutes in laravel. I have read the laravel documentation with the cron('') function that only performs the correct action for the time specified in cron(''), it does not have to be repetitive after a while.

Comment: you may try this package for your cronjob https://github.com/codestudiohq/laravel-totem

Comment: try this: `->cron('*/45 * * * *')`

Comment: @Antu. I would try this library, but it would be better without using the support library

Comment: @Miruku Sheki. It will only run at 45 minutes of each hour, not repeat every 45 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating 3 crons in the Scheduler:

```
...->cron('00,45 */3 * * *');
...->cron('30 1-22/3 * * *');
...->cron('15 2-23/3 * * *');
```

Adapted from: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/cron-every-45-minutes-4175501255/page2.html for laravel